# A combinatorial formula for finding the $N$-th object of a Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: combinatorics

How can I determine the general term of a Fibonacci Sequence? Is it possible for any one to calculate $F_{2013}$ and large numbers like this?
Is there a general formula for the nth term of the Fibonacci Sequence?
 But since a Fibonacci sequence can be interpreted as representing the all possible combinations of ordering $n$ things without moving things more than two places.  If so there must be some combinatorial solution? 
Something by using factorial or something? $( N/k)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: I think there's a Mathologer video where they even derive the formula. I'm not completely sure ... But you can search on YouTube :)

Comment: @bengy, look under "closed form expressions".

Comment: But I don't want a recursive one. Nor do I want just a formula.  Show me the combinatorial one.  Wouldn't it be shorter for you guys to just post it here. Thx

Comment: @bengy Scroll down to "Closed-form expression" and "Computation by rounding". To see how it's derived, try this book, for example: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf

Comment: For an explicit formula see: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler-Binet_Formula

BTW $F_{2013}$ is a "big" number: wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fibonacci(2013)

Comment: With a bit of research, you can easily figure it out. Or, if you are familiar with the *Lucas Numbers*, even better